# how do I fake the UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked for a UIWebVIew

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, uiwebview

My problem is the site I'm using in my UIWebView uses Javascript to open a link

```
 window.open source, '_blank' //coffeescript
```

Here is my current code I use to catch links... (doesn't work) and in theory, open them in safari. What happens is on click this code DOES in fact fire and ends up with UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther as the UIWebViewNavigationType

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView!, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest!, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    println("inside")
    var req = request.URL
    println(req.scheme)
    if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked {
        println("false")
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(request.URL)
        return false
    }
    println("true")
    return true
}
```

I pretty much always end up with UIWebViewNavigationType.other as the url type... is there anything I can do in the window.open to force the linkClicked type to happen? or send some custom information through the window.open that I can read on my end? I wanted to avoid a url?clicked=1 approach.

I'm open to ideas here...

Comment: How about having the same JS code that launches the new window change the style of the link to make it look visited. A better way may be to add it to the history, and then the Web View will consider it visited.

Comment: Well I want to catch the link and open it in safari if it isn't relative. That's the end goal here.. I pretty much have to catch it at this point to handle the redirect properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fake a onclick event from javascript you need to do something like this..

```
var aTag = document.createElement('a');
aTag.setAttribute('href',"http://www.google.com");
aTag.innerHTML = "link text";
aTag.click()
```

the above code will hit the UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked

```
window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
```

the above code will trigger UIWebViewNavigationType.other